# How to modify NGX Bootstrap carousel indicators to improve accessibility?

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using `"ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",` carousel component. I'd like to make my website more accessible for people with disabilities. Unfortunately I can't find a way to modify slide indicators so that they could be accessible using keyboard. Is there a way to do it?

Here's what I got:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators ng-star-inserted">
    <li class="ng-star-inserted"></li>
    <li class="ng-star-inserted active"></li>
</ol>
```

And what I want:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators ng-star-inserted">
  <li class="ng-star-inserted" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-pressed="false"></li>
  <li class="ng-star-inserted active" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-pressed="true"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Have u tried adding `(keydown)="prevKeydown($event)"` and in your .ts `prevKeydown(event: any) {
    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
      this.previousSlide();
     } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
      this.nextSlide();
     }
    }` etc. ?

Comment: What you propose is making available to switch it using arrows. I will consider it thanks for tip. Problem is that indicators are not focusable at all they don't have tabindex and are just `li` elements.

Comment: A person that is sight-impaired wouldn't know when it reached the next & previous indicators via tabs anyway unless you provide audio feedback, so providing arrow-navigation is definitly helpful to comply with [WAI](https://www.w3.org/WAI/)

Comment: I really like that you are taking WAI into consideration - no matter how you want to implement it - so +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround. Basically I did hide original indicators and created my own.

```
<carousel [noPause]="false" [(activeSlide)]="activeSlide" [showIndicators]="false">
      <slide *ngFor="let item of items">
      ...
      </slide>
  <!-- add this -->
  <div class="indicators">
    <button *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" type="button" class="indicator"
            [class.active]="i === activeSlide" [attr.aria-pressed]="i === activeSlide"
            (click)="switchSlide(i)"></button>
  </div>
 <!-- /add this -->
</carousel>
```

This way you got total control over indicators and you can style it whatever you want and you can modify it way it will be accessible.

Comment: nice workaround ;) Did you encounter any functionality-issues with the carousel-component?

Comment: Personally I find it very nice and did not have any problems.

Comment: Then you might want to accept your own answer in case no other answer that solves this isssue natively will be posted for a while..