# How can I make ng-bootstrap carousel slide indicators more accessible?

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, carousel

I'm doing some accessibility work with tab and clicking enter and before writing a bunch of hacky code wanted to see if there was an easy solution.

The bottom portion of the carousel has little indicators where you can click them and they change the corresponding slide. The problem is, they've used list item elements alone instead of buttons or anchors and the click events associated with each indicator is tied in to the specific list item instead of a button which has the built in accessibility.

I'd like to be able to tab through the indicators and trigger each by clicking enter. Currently I'm adding tab indexes to the list items to even be able to tab through, but if there's an easier way to control all this then that would be ideal.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to show some code, and your post title should be a clear, specific question and not just the declaration that you're having issues. We're _all_ having issues.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? Bootstrap 5 uses buttons for the slide indicators. Bootstrap 4 makes it clear in [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/) that their are accessibility failings with the library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify NGX Bootstrap carousel indicators to improve accessibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825800/ngx-bootstrap-carousel-how-to-modify-indicators-improve-accessibility)